About dimensions of quotients of quasi projective varieties
This question is related to this one. If I have an locally closed, quasi projective scheme $X$ contained in an affine space, and a linearly reductive group $G$ acting freely on $X$, are there examples where the dimension $\dim X - \dim G$  is not realized by any of its irreducible components?

Irreducible components of what?

Ok, I am assuming that the quotient space is indeed a scheme. Is it too strong?

Yes. Have a look at Mumford's Geometric Invariant Theory, chapter I.

So, I took a look at Mumford's book, but this is not quite yet what I am asking. I understand things could go wrong in the quotient and that is why he developed the theory of quotients with linearized sheaves, but what I am looking for is a concrete example where the quotient does not work, besides the classical one of C^* acting on A^n, because there, the action is not free.

If I understand your question correctly, there is no such example.
Let $G$ act on $X$ freely. Then, by definition, for each $x \in X$ the orbit map $\alpha_x : G \to X$ sending $g \mapsto g \cdot x$ is injective. Therefore, $\dim(G \cdot x) = \dim(G)$ for each orbit.
By the closed orbit lemma (p.26 of Brian Conrad's notes) all orbits are closed (since they all have the same dimension, they are all minimal).
Therefore, the map $X \to X / G$ actually parametrizes orbits in the sense that the fiber over $[x] \in X / G$ is exactly the orbit $G \cdot x$. Therefore, $\dim(X/G) = \dim(X) - \dim(G)$ and in fact is equidimensional iff $X$ is because all of the fibers of $X \to X / G$ are of dimension $\dim(G)$.

So, the only thing that I need to check is the fact that the space of all closed orbits is indeed a scheme? If it is, then the dimension coincides with dim(X) - dim(G). Right?

In fact, since you assume X is quasi-affine (an open in an affine scheme) the quotient always exists as a scheme. This is because the trivial bundle gives a linearization of the action and the closedness of the orbits shows that the entire space is GIT stable. More generally, if G acts freely the quotient exists as an algebraic space and the same proof shows it has the expected dimension
